# How to query in django model having fields as foreign keys?

Tags: django, django-models, django-filter

Models.py :.

```
  class Match(models.Model):
    rep_broker = models.ForeignKey('account.User', related_name='rep_broker',on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    boat = models.ForeignKey('boat.Boat', related_name='matches', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

How to query the Match model to get the output like "rep_broker have 3 boats matching"

table example:

```
broker1 | boat1  
broker1 | boat2 
broker2 | boat3
```

output  :  broker1 have 2 boats matching
broker2 have 1 boat matching

Output should be list of dictionary

```
[{"name":"broker1","no_of_boats":"2"},{"name":"broker2","no_of_boats":"1"}}
```

Comment: How should the dictionary look like? The key of a dictionary can only occur *once*.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem please check again..i have added

Comment: what is the `name` of the `Broker`, does the `User` has a `name` field?

Comment: Yes.user have name field

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Broker can have multiple boats.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the `Match` objects and the corresponding `User` (broker) and `Boat`s with a query and the post-process that query with [**`.groupby(…)`** [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import attrgetter

qs = Match.objects.select_related('rep_broker', 'boat').order_by('rep_broker')

result = {
    k: [v.boat for v in vs]
    for k, vs in groupby(qs, attrgetter('rep_broker'))
}
```

This will produce a dictionary that maps the `User` objects to lists of `Boat` objects, given the `User` of course matches with *at least* one `Boat`.

In case you want the *number* of `Boat`s, you can create a query to annotate the `User` objects with:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

result = list(User.objects.values(
    'name'
).annotate(
    no_of_boats=Colaesce(Count('rep_broker'), Value(0))
))
```

This will construct a list of dictionaries. This is however a [*primitive obsession* antipattern [refactoring.guru]](https://refactoring.guru/smells/primitive-obsession). You might want to annotate the `User` objects itself:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

qs = User.objects.annotate(
    no_of_boats=Coalesce(Count('rep_broker'), Value(0))
))
```

The `User` objects that arise from *this* queryset will simply have an extra attribute `.no_of_boats`, but thus the logical layer the `User` model offers still persists.

You can filter out `User`s with no match to a boat in this case with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

qs = User.objects.filter(
    rep_broker__isnull=False
).annotate(
    no_of_boats=Count('rep_broker'))
))
```

Comment: How can i get User objects from sef.matches ,,,without directly using the User model.

Comment: @MallusMedia: you can use `get_user_Model()` to retrieve a reference to the model class of the specified user model: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model